# Disable select options

Tags: jquery

I have `2 select boxes`. What I need to do is: when the `1st select option` I chosen to enable `2nd select options` and then when I chose option,it ads it self to a `ol li` list and disables that option. When I click on `li` the `li` should disappear and option on second select box should be enabled.

```
<div class="styleSelect">
    <select class="units" id="select">
        <option value="1">Sve ponude</option>
        <option value="2">1</option>
        <option value="3">2</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="styleSelect">
    <select class="units" id="change">
        <option value="1" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Sve ponude</option>
        <option value="2">1</option>
        <option value="3">2</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div>
    <ol>
    </ol>
</div>
```

jquery:

```
                function getText(){
                $('#change').on('change',function(){
                    $(".value_change").prop('value', 'Potvrdi');
                    $("#close").css('display', 'none');
                    conceptName ='<li>' + $('#change').find(":selected").text() + ' ( ' + $('#select').find(":selected").text() + ' ) <a  class="speclist-remove"></a></li>';
                    $('ol').append(conceptName);    
                    $('#change').on('change',function(){
                        if($(this).val()){
                            $(this).prop("disabled",true);
                        }
                    });
                        $(".speclist-remove").on("click", function(){
                            $(this).closest("li").remove();
                            alert($(this).closest("li").text());
                        });

                });     
            }
```

Comment: Have you tried something? SO isn't here to write the code for you :) Please include your attempts in the question :)

Comment: You forgot to post JavaScript/jQuery script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite sure correct or not, try this example usage :

**HTML**

```
<div class="styleSelect">
  <select class="units" id="select">
    <option value="1">Sve ponude</option>
    <option value="2">1</option>
    <option value="3">2</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="styleSelect">
<select class="units" id="change">
    <option value="1" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Sve ponude</option>
    <option value="2">1</option>
    <option value="3">2</option>
</select>
</div>
<div>
 <ol></ol>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).on('change', '#select', function(){    
  var val = $(this).val();
  $('ol').append('<li>'+val+'</li>');
  $('#change option[value="'+val+'"]').prop('disabled', true);    
});

$(document).on('click','ol li',function(){
  var val = $(this).text().trim();
  $(this).remove();
  $('#change option[value="'+val+'"]').prop('disabled', false);
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/norlihazmeyGhazali/d8yxxxhc/)

Comment: close but not correct. when 2nd option is chosen it should ad to ol and only 2nd select options should be disabled,1st select options is enabled.

Comment: That mean, option only disable on it own after change event

Comment: that is it. thanks. :D Well 2 more things. can it show text and not value and show text of both selected options?

Comment: i need when 1st select option is clicked and 2nd select option is clicked to put both text in li. and when 1st select option is changed to be able to add more options of 2nd select. Kinda complicated :/

Comment: Check demo link. Answer updated for text output instead value. But for last requirement did't get it what you want to achieve.

Comment: text from both select boxes should append to li but only 2nd select box options disabled

Comment: thanks it works now. one more question is there a way to change select options? like if i chose option 1 in select 1,options of select 2 would be 1 and 2,and if i chose option 2 in select 1,options of select 2 would be 3 and 4.

Comment: Yes you can, make if else condition like choose option 1 appended option into 1 and 2 values.

Comment: just click on buttons until you see 2 select boxes. the ones that this question was about. chose options,close it and click on link. then to it the same thing. you will see that it puts 2 options in ol,close it again and do ti all again and you will see that it puts 3 options in ol,and so on. I cant find the bug.